# Rspamd + Redis: Is it necessary to persist Redis database? If yes, how?

Tags: redis, rspamd

I am using rspamd and I have enabled Redis. To my understandind Redis is an *in-memory* key-value *cache* for *volatile* data. However, the rspamd documentation says that the Baysian classifier module uses Redis to store *non-volatile* statistics about ham/spam which the classifier has learned. This puzzles me.

Currently, I see the following warnings in my logs

```
rspamd[515182]: <6853da>; proxy; rspamd_redis_connected: skip obtaining bayes tokens for BAYES_HAM of classifier bayes: not enough learns 19; 200 required
rspamd[515182]: <6853da>; proxy; rspamd_redis_connected: skip obtaining bayes tokens for BAYES_SPAM of classifier bayes: not enough learns 4; 200 required
```

This is fine for me, because I have set up my mail server and rspamd only recently. The 19 ham and 4 spam tokens originate from some initial testing which I performed with Sieve scripts and the `learn-ham`, `learn-spam` scripts. So it is correct, indeed, that rspamd has not yet seen enough training data.

However, this all makes me wonder, if I have to backup the Redis database. Assume the mail server has run for quite a while, Rspamd has been trained based on real spam/ham from users and then the server or the Redis daemon is restarted. Will all the training data be lost? This doesn't sound right.

But to my understanding Redis is not supposed to be used for persistent data storage and there is also no warning in the rspamd documentation that one should persist the Redis database.

Answer (score 0):

> to my understanding Redis is not supposed to be used for persistent data storage

According to Redis' own [About](https://redis.io/docs/about/) page persistence is a very valid use case:

> Redis has built-in replication, Lua scripting, LRU eviction, transactions, and different levels of **on-disk persistence**, and provides high availability via Redis Sentinel and automatic partitioning with Redis Cluster.

There is also [thorough documentation](https://redis.io/docs/management/persistence/) about the different persistence options.